# CasperJS back navigation doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, navigation, casperjs

Here's the situation:

1. I use CasperJS to open a `page`
2. I click on button on the `page` to go to `page2`
3. I click a button on `page2` to go to `page3`

Now I am on page 3 and I call `this.back()` within a then statement and it does go back to page 2 and everything just stops executing after that

I also tried to call

```
this.then(function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
        history.go(-1);
    });
});
```

and it goes back to `page2` and gets stuck again. The next line won't execute.

Any ideas or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3):

Typically, the following code works for me:

```
casper.then(function () {
    this.back();
});
```

Make sure you are running on a step your code and finally, in a separate step, the step of returning the page. This is necessary so that your `.back` be done AFTER your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the existing PhantomJS WebPage instance via [`page`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#page) and call the [`goBack()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/go-back.html) method:

```
casper.then(function () {
  this.page.goBack();
});
```